# Update Azure APIM Operation Name After Creation

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to change the `operation name` (a.k.a. `operationId`) of an Azure APIM operation *after* it has been created?

In the example below, I would like the auto-generated `name` of `5dk6e437e1fd991b3df455ff` to be `get-branding-information`:

[image: Sample auto-generated APIM operation name]

Changing the name is not currently supported through the Azure portal UI, but perhaps it is possible through another method?  Since this URL only relates to the APIM documentation pages and is *not* the actual API URL, changing the name wouldn't be a breaking API change for our customers.

Developers who created the original operations on my team got a little lazy and just let the Azure portal assign an auto-generated name to multiple operations.  As a result, I cannot create relative URL reference to different operations within the APIM documentation as the name value is unique in our development, QA, and production APIM environments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your screenshot didn't go quite high enough to show the 'OpenAPI specification View' button.  Click this and you can edit the name.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That works.  I never would've thought to click there.