# Update Azure APIM Name (Api.Id) after cloning using Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-api-management, ibm-api-management, apim

Is it possible to manually change the API Name (a.k.a. Api.Id) of an Azure API after it has been created to something else (I understand that it has to be unique).

When creating a new API, the name (Api.Id) is user-friendly (e.g. same as the display name but all lower case with dashes). If this API is cloned, then the Name (Api.Id) becomes a GUID and is no longer user-friendly. I would like to update it so I can enter a human meaningful Name (e.g. lowercase with dashes... )

EDIT: The question is not about how to rename an "API Operation Name" when having cloned an operation. My question is about renaming an "API Name" when having cloned an API.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**One of the workarounds to rename the cloned API in APIM Instance is**:

Go to the **APIM Instance** > **APIs** > Select your **API** > Select the **Operation** you want to rename it > Click on ***Pencil*** Icon as shown here:
[image]

Now Click on **Open Specification view** Option:
[image]

Change the Operation Id on the Open Specification View Code displayed for that API:

[image: clonedapimrenamingbykrish]

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, the question is not about how to rename an "API Operation Name" when having cloned an operation. My question is about renaming an "API Name" when having cloned an API.

Comment: Yes @Alex, I too cloned an API in APIM, and it given me a alpha-numeric ID like yours as shown in my screenshots. We cannot edit that API name in the box directly, we have to change through code using Open Specification view!

Comment: The Name Value you highlighted is the Operation Name (also known as operation id) of an Azure APIM Cloned API. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62761723).

Comment: MY screenshot (the one on the question), does not highlight an operation name. I know I can change the cloned operation name by editing the yaml (but that is not my scenario).  The problem is with API name (the portal allows specifying one initially but not for a cloned API as far as I can see  (which is pretty bad). See how my screenshot is on the "Settings" tabs and includes API (and not operation) settings like the URL schema and and API Uri Prefix (it is not on the 'Frontend' screen as in your screenshot)

Comment: Hello @Alex, I tried in the [Cloned API Level](https://i.imgur.com/gfGnKvD.png) instead of Operation Level, it's not changing. You are correct! it is not possible, but I will get the confirmation and will keep you posted.

Comment: Could you please give this as a feature request in Azure Platform - https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/e808a70c-ff24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858

Comment: Good idea,  I requested this feature. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select the **API**, Select the **Settings** tab, Change the **Display name**. Select **Save**.

You do not need to touch the operations.